# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PROCEDURE'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Execute following statement in the SQL Server

```
IF  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[SP_CandidateRegistration]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
BEGIN
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_CandidateRegistration]
    (
            @UserName VARCHAR(50),      
            @Password VARCHAR(50),
            @EmailID VARCHAR(50),
            @TestId int,
            @IsActiveUser INTEGER,      
            @USER_ID INTEGER OUTPUT
    )
    AS
    DECLARE @UserName VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @Password VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @EmailID VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @TestId int
    DECLARE @IsActiveUser INTEGER       
    DECLARE @USER_ID INTEGER 

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[IER_CandidateRegistration](User_Name, Password, EmailId, Test_Id, is_active )
    VALUES (@UserName, @Password, @EmailID,@TestId, @IsActiveUser) 
    select @USER_ID=@@identity
    RETURN
END
GO
```

Error after executing in SQL Server 2008

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PROCEDURE'.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can run the `CREATE` in a child batch that is only compiled and executed `IF NOT EXISTS`.

You will need to fix the errors in the procedure first (why are you trying to declare variables with the same name as the parameters also use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` not `@@IDENTITY`) but something like

```
IF  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[SP_CandidateRegistration]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
BEGIN
EXEC('
     CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_CandidateRegistration] (@UserName     VARCHAR(50),
                                                       @Password     VARCHAR(50),
                                                       @EmailID      VARCHAR(50),
                                                       @TestId       INT,
                                                       @IsActiveUser INTEGER,
                                                       @USER_ID      INTEGER OUTPUT)
    AS
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[IER_CandidateRegistration]
                    (User_Name,
                     Password,
                     EmailId,
                     Test_Id,
                     is_active)
        VALUES      (@UserName,
                     @Password,
                     @EmailID,
                     @TestId,
                     @IsActiveUser)

        SELECT @USER_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

RETURN 
    ')
END
```

NB: This question was asked in 2013 (about SQL Server 2008) but since SQL Server 2016 it has been possible to do `CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE` to avoid the need for any `IF NOT EXISTS` type procedural code at all.

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal - there aren't any here

Answer (score 10):

The `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement cannot be combined with other `Transact-SQL` statements in a single batch.
So,You have to do like this:-

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[SP_CandidateRegistration]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [SP_CandidateRegistration]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_CandidateRegistration]
    (
            @UserName VARCHAR(50),      
            @Password VARCHAR(50),
            @EmailID VARCHAR(50),
            @TestId int,
            @IsActiveUser INTEGER,      
            @USER_ID INTEGER OUTPUT
    )
    AS

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[IER_CandidateRegistration](User_Name, Password, EmailId, Test_Id, is_active )
    VALUES (@UserName, @Password, @EmailID,@TestId, @IsActiveUser) 
    select @USER_ID=@@identity
    RETURN

GO
```

Also, you are again declaring the variables.

Comment: This will also drop any metadata about the procedure such as permissions, execution plans, historic usage stats in the DMVs

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[SP_CandidateRegistration]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_CandidateRegistration]
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_CandidateRegistration]
    (
            @UserName VARCHAR(50),      
            @Password VARCHAR(50),
            @EmailID VARCHAR(50),
            @TestId int,
            @IsActiveUser INTEGER,      
            @USER_ID INTEGER OUTPUT
    )
    AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @UserName1 VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @Password1 VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @EmailID1 VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @TestId1 int
    DECLARE @IsActiveUser1 INTEGER       
    DECLARE @USER_ID1 INTEGER 

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[IER_CandidateRegistration](User_Name, Password, EmailId, Test_Id, is_active )
    VALUES (@UserName, @Password, @EmailID,@TestId, @IsActiveUser) 
    select @USER_ID=@@identity
    RETURN
END
GO
```

Comment: Seems the same as Pranav's suggestion?

Comment: yeah I saw his solution after posting the answer